# Ionice And Apache2

Tags: ionice

I am trying to run apache2 at real time priority for this I want to use IONICE but have not been successful.

Debian 6 (2.6.32-5-amd64)

I use this command

`ionice -c1 -n0 apache2`

But I get this error

`apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}`

Can anyone give me some suggestions to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You should not start apache directly, use an initscript or `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl` for this instead. You should modify `/etc/init.d/apache2` initscript to alter I/O priority. By the way, why do you want to alter the I/O priority of apache processes? This can lead to major problems in case of high number of client requests, the whole system can get unresponsive.

Comment: I started with this command ionice -c1 -n0 /etc/init.d/apache2 start but how should I edit the startup script. The web server is password protected and only used by a few users so there should not be a large amount of requests.